# How to prove that two mobiles will be the closest at time $(dp.dv) / ||dv||²$

Tags: vectors

I have two mobiles, I know their positions and velocities. I want to be able to determine in how many time they will be the closest if they still move at the same velocity.
In a book I read, they present this formula : 
$t_{closest} = \frac{dp.dv}{||dv||²}$

With :

- Considering all in 2D
- $t_{closest}$ is in how many time they will be the closest possible
- $dp = p_2 - p_1$
- $p_1$ = position of mobile 1 at start
- $p_2$ = position of mobile 2 at start
- $dv = v_2 - v_1$
- $v_1$ = velocity of mobile 1 at start
- $v_2$ = velocity of mobile 2 at start
- ||dv|| is the magnitude of dv

I try it and it works, but I didn't succeed at demonstrating it

Is someone able to explain me how demonstrate this formula?

Thank you,

Comment: Do they move on a plane ? What are their initial positions ?

Comment: Yes I consider only 2D. p1 and p2 are their initials positions. v1 & v2 their velicity and t_closest will be "in how many time do they will be the closer possible"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position at time $t$ of the two mobiles are resp. $p_1+tv_1$ and $p_2+tv_2$.

Their **squared** distance is :

$$d(t)=\|(p_2+tv_2)-(p_1+tv_1)\|^2=\|(p_2-p_1)+t(v_2-v_1)\|^2=\|dp+t \ dv\|^2=(dp+t \ dv).(dp+t \ dv)$$

(Squared norm is the same as squared dot product). Expanding :

$$d(t)=t^2\underbrace{\|dv\|^2}_A+t \underbrace{(2 dp.dv)}_{B} +\underbrace{\|dp\|^2}_{C}.$$

$d(t)$ is a quadratic in $t$ with leading coefficient $A>0$.

In such a case, it is well known that it has a minimum occuring for

$$t=-\dfrac{B}{2A}=\color{red}{-}\dfrac{dp.dv}{\|dv\|^2}$$

as desired (but with a minus sign).

Remark : Subtracting position and speed of mobile n° 2 to mobile n°1, is equivalent to estimate a relative position, that can be explained as the trajectory of mobile n°2 as seen **on the radar** of mobile n°1.

Comment: No comment ? Are you comfortable with vector tools like norms, dot products... ?

Comment: I didn't get time to look at it in details. Thank, I understand now :) --  I the demonstration I saw nothing which limit the space of this formula to be size 2, am I right?

Comment: You are completely right : the formula is valid for example in 3D for computing the instant of shortest distance between the trajectories of 2 planes having a linear trajectory.

Comment: I have corrected a sign error.